# Is the finding trace of the Riemann tensor the same thing as contracting two indices?

Tags: tensors, trace

To form the Ricci curvature tensor, we have to take the trace of the Riemann tensor. But I also know 
\begin{equation}
R_{ij} := R_{kij}^{\phantom{kij}k} 
\end{equation}

**Can someone show me why taking the trace is the same thing as contracting indices?**

Comment: What did you try? Did you try to do a computation with 2-tensors (aka matrices)?

Comment: No. I saw this on Wikipedia and my GR and math texts, but no one I've read explains how to do it. Perhaps they think it trivial. but I've wondered this for several months how / why this is so and just thought I'd ask on Math SE to see if someone could help me out.

Comment: I thought it would be straight forward to answer. I just have no idea how to do it.

Comment: As I said, try this for matrices, where matrix coefficients are written as $(a_i^j)$ instead of $(a_{ij})$ as in your linear algebra class. Can you do this?

Comment: Oh! Sorry I get now. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. Now, you can answer your own question and accept the answer!

Comment: They are the same by definition - it's just different terminology meaning the same thing. There is nothing to prove...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following matrix

\begin{equation}
A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c \\
d & e & f \\ 
g & h & i \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

By definition, the trace of $A$ is defined as

\begin{equation} 
\text{tr}(A) = a + e + i = a_{11} + a_{22} + a_{33}
\end{equation}

So think about how we write tensor indices. If I have a tensor $a_{ij}$ and I contract one index to get $a_i^i$, now both indices have the same value. So for all values of $i$ in this case we would have $a_1^1$, $a_2^2$, $a_3^3$, which corresponds to $a$,$e$,$i$.

Thus, contracting indices gives the same value as taking the trace.